# What's the rule of using "After" as conjunction in different tenses?

Tags: grammar, tense, conjunctions, clauses, time-words

I am having confusion in this gramatical part.

**Which Sentence is correct here?**

**1/I shall inform you after I have had the news**

2/**I shall inform you after I have the news**

What's the gramatical rule of using after in time clauses,I didn't get any satisfied answer in web.

Comment: Neither is grammatically wrong, but in this context it would be more natural to say "I shall inform you _when_ I have (or get) the news."  But we would say "I will go there after I have had my meal."

Comment: You might say that the perfect is redundant here because the past/anterior meaning is conveyed by _after_.

Answer (score 1):

As Kate pointed out, in your particular example "when" would be better than "after". But since you're curious about "after", let's talk a little more about it. The choice of tense depends on the context.

Here are some examples with the present simple tense:

> I'll come to your place after I **pick up** the kids from school.
>
> We'll probably get some dinner after we **watch** the game.

Both sentences have the basic structure of "**A** will happen after **B**", and the **B** is not what's interesting - rather, the emphasis is on **A** (coming to your place, getting dinner). Compare this with the following examples using the present perfect:

> I'll go there after I **have finished** my meal.
>
> Our guests will join us after they **have checked in** to their hotel.

The structure here is again "**A** will happen after **B**", but now we're putting a little more emphasis on the **B** (finishing the meal, checking in) by indicating it's going to take some time, so **A** will have to wait until **B** is done.

This isn't meant to describe a formal grammatical rule - I'm just trying to give you a taste for the difference.